# XMMS2: set notifications on title change

Tags: c, media-player

I am attempting to set a notification for a title change in XMMS2 for a radio station.  I found the values for status changes but none of them seem to correspond to this sort of change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think xmmsc_broadcast_medialib_entry_changed is the function you are looking for

Comment: yep, you'll get the medialib id, and if it matches the id of the currently playing track, then you can then use `xmmsc_medialib_get_info` to get the title.